# Why my exception doesn't work

Tags: java, exception

If the input customer name is null, the exception is supposed to throw, but my code didn't work.

```
public class CustomerAccount {
    private String name;

    public CustomerAccount(String name) throws IllegalArgumentException {

        this.setName(name);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        try {
            this.name = name;

        }

        catch (IllegalArgumentException illegal) {
            if (name == "" || name == null) {
                System.err.println("please do not enter the empty string" + illegal);
            }

        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Name: " + this.getName();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CustomerAccount c1 = new CustomerAccount("random name");

        c1.setName(null);
        System.out.println(c1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please use the tags to categorise your question properly so the right people will see it. At a minimum you should have included the [tag:java] tag (which someone has now added for you).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

setName should simply throw the IllegalArgumentException if name is null or empty (no try/catch within that method).

```
public void setName(String name) throws IllegalArgumentException {
   if ("".equals(name) || name == null) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Name should not be null or empty");
   }
   this.name=name;

 }
```

Comment: String comparison should use .equals too.

Comment: Yep - I'll update my answer thanks!    String s1 = "";
  String s2 = " ".trim();
  System.out.println(s1==s2); //false

Comment: Thanks a lot, but can you explain why I can't use catch and try for this method.

Comment: Sure, you use Try / Catch to handle and recover from exceptions that have been thrown already, at the point in your code where you can recover from the error. But you use throw to create the Exception at the point where the error occurs. In your case having a null name is the error, so here you throw the Exception. Somewhere else you may decide to handle that exception and that's where you put the try /catch.

Answer (score 0):

Use `name.equals("")`

 Better to use `equals()` for String comparison.

Comment: `name.equals("")` requires that `name` be checked for `null` first, tho. Better swap the literal and the variable.

Comment: ok. What i meant was instead of `name == ""` use `name.equals("")` or `"".equals(name)`

Answer (score 0):

**The mere assignment of a null value does not trigger an exception!**

What's more, in the spirit of *fail-fast*, method argument validation is typically done first thing in a method implementation. Also, `name == ""` is unlikely to work, since `name` is probably set at runtime and therefore assigned a different memory address as `""`. Last but not least, convention dictates the use of `NullpointerException` rather than a `IllegalArgumentException` (see Effective Java Item 60).

Adding all this up, you could implement the method like this:

```
public void setName(@Nonnull final String name) {

  if (name == null || name.length() == 0) {
    throw new NullPointerException("[name] must not be null or empty.");
  } 

  this.name = name;
}
```

Since this is sort of check is something you are likely to do a lot of times in your code, I suggest the use of a library function for the check:

**With Guava:**

```
Preconditions.checkArgument(name != null && name.length() > 0, "[name] must not be null or empty.");
```

**With Apache Commons:**

```
if (StringUtils.isEmpty(name)) {
  throw new NullPointerException("[name] must not be null or empty.");
}
```

Comment: Instead of manually throwing an NPE, consider throwing IllegalArgumentException instead. NPEs are usually signs of bugs, not of intended (error) behaviour.

Comment: @hiergiltdiestfu Don't agree and neither does Josh Bloch. Check Effective Java Item 60.

Comment: Oh you even addressed that issue in your answer, sorry. Nonetheless, I disagree with "convention dictates". One book doesn't make that canon :) The Javadoc for NPE pretty clearly says that it's intended for cases where the null ref is already being used in place of an object. This is not the case in that isEmpty-test.